# Copy standard input, run two tasks, while reserving the order of output lines?

Tags: shell, tee

I want to write a one-line-command to do two tasks with the same copy of stdin. Here is the example:

```
% echo "Victor\nHugo" | tee >(wc -l) | grep "V"
```

The result will finally saved into a file, to be processed by my program. And what I expect to get is:

```
2
Victor
```

However, sometimes, the order of output might be reversed, if `wc` happens to be slower:

```
% echo "Victor\nHugo" | tee >(sleep 1s; wc -l) | grep "V"
Victor
2
```

Maybe I should not use `tee` like this? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: [What are you *really* trying to do](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: @ghoti updated the question, if it is still confusing, thank you for telling me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single pipe, with awk:

```
printf "Victor\nHugo\n" \
| awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {print NR; for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) if (a[i]~/^V/) print a[i];}'
```

It ain't pretty.  And it's more memory-hungry the larger your input dataset.  But it'll provide the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

For this example I think the clearest approach is classic preocedural style:

```
names="Victor\nHugo\n"
printf $names | wc -l
printf $names | grep "V"
```